# Что уместнее использовать RadioButton1Click или Radiobutton1.Checked?

Tags: delphi

Пробую реализовать то, что как-то не могу на php, и хотел бы уточнить, какая конструкция кода уместнее:

```
 procedure TForm1.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   file_name := 'c:\soft\01.docx';
   edit2.Text := file_name;
 end;
```

или

```
if radiobutton1.Checked = true then
begin
  file_name := 'c:\soft\01.docx';
  edit2.Text := file_name;
end;
```

Ведь мне только результат в переменную **file_name** получить, и всё.

---

Результат сую сюда:

```
  Command_Run := 'winword';
  Command_Key := file_name;
  Shellexecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(Command_Run), PChar(Command_Key), nil, SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от контекста, если третий блок кода выполняется, скажем, по нажатию на button (на событие привязан какой-либо хендлер), то 2-й блок кода можно поместить в этот хендлер, но менять можно и так, как в 1-м случае, лично я делал, как в лекциях препода, - 2-й случай.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо присвоение переменной именно в момент нажатия, то в обработчике события, во втором случае можно проверить в любом месте программы и присвоить. Проще использовать первый вариант, в этом случае не нужно будет думать постоянно о том, было ли присвоено значение или нет.
Например, если кнопка была нажата, а потом нажата другая из той же группы, то первая отожмётся, тогда при проверке программа не присвоит переменную.